# I can't create a new web project in eclipse luna IDE (do not find create new web project)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I download [this Eclipse Luna](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar), for java EE developers, as seen in the description, it supports web applications. I can't find

> file -> new -> other -> web projects

in this version. I looked everywhere and didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name has been changed from `web projects` to `Dynamic web projects` in `luna`.

```
file>new>other>(type web)>Dynamic web projects.
```

if you are unable to find Dynamic web projects then follow

```
help>install new software>(find a category "web")
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I don't know why in this version you need to install it when in olders it cames with eclipse.

Comment: @JamesB I'm kind of sure that you download the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers but you should download the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.